# Meaning of "press upon"

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

In [Abraham Lincoln's Inaugural Address](http://www.bartleby.com/124/pres31.html),

> I now reiterate these sentiments, and in doing so I only **press upon** the public attention the most conclusive evidence of which the case is susceptible that the property, peace, and security of no section are to be in any wise endangered by the now incoming Administration.

Is *press upon* used as a phrasal verb here?  Or is it a verb (press) + preposition (upon)?
What's the meaning of *press upon*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is being used as a phrasal verb:

http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/press+upon.html

> Phrasal Verb: Press upon
>
> Meaning: Pressure someone to accept something offered
>
> Example: The invitations were PRESSED UPON us and it was hard to say no.

Note that it's usually a fairly mild pressure.  It's not like the Godfather-esque *"offer you can't refuse"*.